# Is this good URL design practice in React?

Tags: reactjs, url, url-design

I start out in a listview where each item in the listview is an item each with a unique _id displaying only partial information, clicking on them will route to another page and display all the info. Now, I click on an item, route to the unique id and a brand new component, then, in the new component, I take that unique ID, search up that unique ID in my MongoDB database, then display the item that was found.

If not, what is a better way? I was trying to model youtube's URL design (at least what it appears to me), in the home page, they display many videos, and then on click, they route to /watch + specific id, and then display the video.

Comment: As per my knowledge That’s fairly good approach

Comment: I agree with @HemadriDasari, it is a good approach.